# Cannot add column of type numeric[][] in DataGrip for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Simple enough...

I want to use `numeric[][]` for a column in a PostgreSQL table in DataGrip, but whenever I specify it and click on "save", the IDE decides to change it to `numeric[]`.

Infuriating.

No error, just silently messes up my schema.

Why JetBrains?

Comment: I see you reported issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-18177. Please follow it for updates.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's more complex problem. DataGrip doesn't introspect multidimensional arrays correctly.

Follow the issue [Multidimensional arrays are introspected without dimension information](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-18177/Multidimensional-arrays-are-introspected-without-dimension-information) to be up to date

Comment: Yeah I have been getting lots of emails about it, thanks!

Comment: I hope, the fix will be delivered in the nearest major release.